# Rails 3 - how to hide a graphic if file is missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but am having difficulty with !=nil syntax in multiple places in my app.  In this example, I want to show an icon with links only if there is a hyperlink in the database.  Unfortunately, the icons show in my view whether or not the urls are empty/nil.

```
<% if @host.home_url != nil  %>
    <%= link_to(image_tag("icon_website_32.png", :border=>0), @host.home_url) %>
<% end %>
```

I'm having the same issue trying to hide a second line of an address if there isn't one:

```
<% if location.street_address2 != nil  %>
     <%= location.street_address2 %><br />
<% end %>
```

Any advice for a marketing chick turned newbie programmer?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, how do people make their code easy to read on Stack Overflow?

Comment: is it empty string or is it nil? because `"".nil? # => false` and `"".empty? # => true`

Comment: Welcome to programming, and welcome to Rails :)  You will find lots of help for that here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `present?` method here. And you can use it inline

```
<%= link_to image_tag("icon_website_32.png", :border=>0), @host.home_url if @host.home_url.present? %>
```

Comment: yeah, this is the most straightforward way since `present?` is the opposite of `blank?`

Comment: Thank you so much! These examples are great!

Answer (score 1):

Rails adds a method called `blank?` to check whether a value is either nil or an empty string, so...

```
<% unless @host.home_url.blank? %>
  <%= link_to(image_tag("icon_website_32.png", :border=>0), @host.home_url) %>
<% end %>
```

To get a feel for this, play with it in the Rails console (`script/console` in Rails 2.x, or `rails console` in Rails 3).

```
>> nil.blank?
=> true
>> ''.blank?
=> true
>> 'abc'.blank?
=> false
```

BTW, you would conventionally check for plain ol' non-nil in Ruby using `!var.nil?` rather than 'var != nil`.

Comment: Awesome!  This solves about 12 different problems at once!  Thank you so much!